# Exoplayer threading errors NoSuchElementExceptionat java.util.ArrayDeque.removeFirst

Tags: java, android, multithreading, exoplayer2.x

I just switched to Exoplayer from MediaPlayer for playing background music in a game application.
During all my tests it seemed to be working fine but after partial release I've started to see crashes in

```
crashalytics:
NoSuchElementException at java.util.ArrayDeque.removeFirst (ArrayDeque.java:264)
com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImpl.notifyListeners (ExoPlayerImpl.java:737)
com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImpl.updatePlaybackInfo (ExoPlayerImpl.java:710)
com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImpl.handlePlaybackInfo (ExoPlayerImpl.java:652)
com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImpl.handleEvent (ExoPlayerImpl.java:595)
com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImpl$1.handleMessage (ExoPlayerImpl.java:127)
```

After googling it seems to have to do with threading and that I need to call it on the same thread that it was created on.
So to my questions on my implementation:
I have a game with 4 activities where one is the game runner.
main activity have one exoplayer
activity 2 have one
activity 3 have one
gameactivity is creating its own inside the game thread

each time I need a exoplayer I call this method:

```
   private SimpleExoPlayer createSimpleExoPlayer(Context context, int resId, boolean repeat) {
        SimpleExoPlayer exoPlayer = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(context).build();
        DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(context,
            Util.getUserAgent(context, "appname"));
        Uri uri = RawResourceDataSource.buildRawResourceUri(resId);
        MediaSource source = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(uri);
        exoPlayer.prepare(source);
        if (repeat)
            exoPlayer.setRepeatMode(Player.REPEAT_MODE_ALL);
        //exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
        return exoPlayer;
    }
```

and a player may be released and recreated when switching background music inside the game loop.
So might that be what is causing the problems?
Have I misunderstood how it works and maybe I should ever only have ONE instance or is it fine to have several instances like I do?
Any advice is most welcome.

Comment: ok, I found logs saying that I was making calls on the wrong thread, so assume that my instance inside the game loop is the problem, have moved it to the game activity and will see if it solves the problem

Comment: So I moved the exoplayer from game loop into the game activity which should be running on the main thread and communicate with broadcast messages from the game loop to the activity, and it removed all the logs but I still get the crash error in crashalytics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had a Timer that called the exoplayer when it expired and therefore calling it from another thread